# jQuery Time Entry plugin support minutes upto 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am using jQuery time entry plugin http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

It works fine as expected. However, I want that the minutes should go upto 100 for eg. I want to treat 0.25 as 15 minutes and not 0.15 as 15 minutes.

I want the display to go upto 100 count. Is this possible to achieve in time entry plugin?

Any solution is helpful.

Comment: No, this isn't possible with this plugin. It's designed to show a valid time. If you want this behaviour, why not just use a `number` input?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I definitely want all of the features of time entry but just need an option some thing like allowminutesupto100 when that is turned on the calculation of minutes is done as per 100 so 25 is counted as 15 minutes 0.5 is counted as 30 minutes.